# open SQL Server Management Studio from another machine

Tags: remote, sql, ssms

I have SQL Management studio installed on my VM and I use VDI to access VM. the only reason i login into VM to access the SSMS. Is there is any way i can open the SSMS from VDI without login in to VM? I cant install the same in VDI. Previous versions of SQL (2000) used to allow this by just executing the SQLComnd.exe from the installed location.

Comment: SSMS is a rich GUI, if you want to run a rich GUI you'd have to access the VM. Is the actual question here "How can I run TSQL from a commandline on newer versions of SQL?" ? (You could also install SSMS on your local machine)